# Notepad++ Search and Replace: delete all after "/" in each row

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a plain text file with content like this:

```
prežrať/RN
prežrieť/Z
prežrúc/zZ
prežuť/c
...
```

**Q: How can I remove all strings after `/` symbol in every row in Notepad++?**

Desired output:

```
prežrať
prežrieť
prežrúc
prežuť
...
```

I am doing this with Find-and-Replace for every different string after `/`, but there are too many combinations.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Search for: `/.*`, replace with nothing.

The character `/` matches just `/`. `.`, however, matches any character except newlines, so `.*` will match a sequence of characters up until the first newline. You can find a demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/kT0uE3.

If you want to remove characters only after the *last* on the line `/`, you should use the regex `/[^/]*$`. You can find an explanation and demonstration here: https://regex101.com/r/sZ6kP7/74.

Answer (score 10):

In regular expression mode

Find:

```
/.*
```

Replace:

```
(empty)
```

Comment: This answer helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Set find and replace to regular expression mode. 
Find string: `/.*` 
Replace String:  (empty string)

Notepad++ find and replace is by default line ended (it won't go over multiple lines)

Answer (score 2):

Using find and replace:

- Hit CTRL-H to open the Replace dialogue box
- enter `/.*` into "Find what"
- leave "Replace with" empty
- Select "Regular expression" (and .matches newline if it is single line)
- Click on Replace

Here we go... You are done.