# How can i filter a big list in a text document

Tags: windows, list, filter

I have a question:

How can I filter a big list in a text document of the following form:

```
asdasd€1oij2
ad-assdaE1pe2€pk
uhuhuh€812u-9eh1
817€2e981ez98
     ...
```

I need 2 remove the part after the € sign (and the € sign) in each line of the list. So the list should look like this :

```
asdasd
ad-assdaE1pe2
uhuhuh
817
     ...
```

Also I need 2 remove every line with a "-" symbol.

I'm on win 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has been already answered here:
[Notepad++ Search and Replace: delete all after "/" in each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163976/notepad-search-and-replace-delete-all-after-in-each-row/21164013)

Also to remove every line that contains something use notepad ++

1. Press CTRL+H
2. Got to the mark tab
3. Tick bookmark line
4. Tick normal on search Mode
5. Click on Mark all
6. Go to Search -> Bookmark -> Remove Bookmarked Lines